# How to minimize RMSE of a regression using optim()?

Tags: r, optimization

I need to minimize RMSE of a linear regression using weights with several parameters.

I tried using optim(), but it gives error - "missing or negative weights not allowed". Weights should not be negative or missing, because output of function changes when parameters change, meaning that weights in regression work.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(MLmetrics)
library(modelr)


ff1 <- function(a){
  data1 <- sim1
  a1 <- a[1]
  a2 <- a[2]
  data1$w <- a1*data1$x + a2*data1$y
  fit <- lm(y ~ x ,data = data1,weights=w)
  x2 <- data.frame(x=data1$x)
  yy <- data.frame(fit = predict(fit,x2))
  data1$fit <- yy$fit
  rmse1 <- RMSE(data1$fit,data1$x)
  return(rmse1)
}

ff1(c(1,1))
ff1(c(1,50))


sol <- optim(c(1,1),ff1)
```

I tried several methods, but they produce the same error.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Which part of it? The function works fine in my case, but optim() does not.

Comment: When I copy-paste your code it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand your point. RMSE is a measure of the fitting performance. To decrease it you need to find a better model. What is your purpose with optim?

Comment: My model has several parameters, such as size of deal and closeness to middle of a month. With weights I was trying to reduce prediction interval.

Comment: weights should be used to review the belief you have in the data, such as how long ago was it. By using them in the way you're trying, you will overfit to your data and your predictions on new data will suffer as a result. I won't review the code itself, but I'd suggest taking a step back to understand what model you want to fit more deeply